# Python/Pyscript asyncio order of events not as expected

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am calling the code below from HTML using `py-script`. I am seeing that the order of events in this simple example is not what I expected. In the output below the displayed events are not in sequence. What am I missing to make my code wait until `getWords()` completes before I continue to process the output?

```py
from request import request
import asyncio
import json

async def getWords():
    print("2. INSIDE GETWORDS:")
    baseurl = "http://localhost:4000/wordscape"

    body = json.dumps({"sqlline": sqlline})
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    response = await request(f"{baseurl}/read", body=body, method="POST", headers=headers)

    my_Words = await response.string()
    print("3. MYWORDS inside getWords:", my_Words)


sqlline = "select upper(word) as word from dictionary.dictionary_words_20230103 where word = 'help'\n"
print("1. BUILD SQL:", sqlline)
my_Words = ''
asyncio.ensure_future(getWords())
print("4. ####WORDS RETURNED FROM getWords:",my_Words)
```

Output:

```
1. BUILD SQL: select upper(word) as word from dictionary.dictionary_words_20230103 where word = 'help'

4. ####WORDS RETURNED FROM getWords: 
2. INSIDE GETWORDS:
3. MYWORDS inside getWords: [
  {
    "word": "HELP"
  }
]
```

Comment: I also tried using pyfetch.  same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with that code. The main problem you are describing comes from the fact that you don't `await` the future that you schedule, when you call `asyncio.ensure_future` on your `getWords` function. It starts running, but you don't wait for it to finish and jump to the `print` call right away.

In fact, you *cannot* await it in the global scope because `await` statements are not allowed outside of `async` functions. This means you need to create some sort of `main` coroutine function for that section of your code. That can  be run from "the outside" via [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run).

This leads right into the next big issue, which is the fact that you are using **global variables** (or more precisely mutating global state). This is almost always a terrible idea.

It is much more prudent to design your `getWords` function in such a way that it takes your `sqlline` as an argument and **returns** the words instead of writing them to a global variable. That way you can just `await` it from any other `async` function and continue processing its output.

Also, as the documentation mentions quite explicitly, you should probably avoid using [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) and use `create_task` instead. But in this case, you need neither of those because you can just await the coroutine directly. I see no use for scheduling it as a task (at least in your example).

Here is a simplified mock-version of your script with some changes:

```py
import asyncio
import json


async def fake_request(_url: str, **_kwargs: object) -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return "foo"


async def get_words(sql_line: str) -> str:
    print("2. INSIDE get_words:")
    baseurl = "http://localhost:4000/wordscape"
    body = json.dumps({"sqlline": sql_line})
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    my_words = await fake_request(
        f"{baseurl}/read", body=body, method="POST", headers=headers
    )
    print("3. my_words INSIDE get_words:", my_words)
    return my_words


async def main() -> None:
    sql = """
    select upper(word) as word from dictionary.dictionary_words_20230103 
    where word = 'help'\n """
    print("1. BUILD SQL:", sql)
    words = await get_words(sql)
    print("4. #### WORDS RETURNED FROM get_words:", words)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I also added type annotations and made the code [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) compliant. Both of those are considered best practices.

Output:

```
1. BUILD SQL: 
    select upper(word) as word from dictionary.dictionary_words_20230103 
    where word = 'help'
 
2. INSIDE get_words:
3. my_words INSIDE get_words: foo
4. #### WORDS RETURNED FROM get_words: foo
```

---

Your question and code show a lot of gaps in fundamental understanding of `asyncio`. I recommend you read up on the basics because you will likely continue to run into such problems, unless you actually grasp the underlying concepts. There is a lot of good and free material out there.

Comment: Thank you for your input and I will give it a try.  I am wondering if all the additional code to use "await" is due to pyscript still being developed.  In JS, simple use of await/async is very straightforward.  Thanks, Dan

Comment: It now works in the correct order.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.